# How to take average of three non empty cells that are not in range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using a VLOOKUP to find three values in a table, that might or might not be there. I want to take average of all values that are found - between 0 to 3 (inclusive) values.

This is the formula I'm using now:

```
=VLOOKUP(AT13,$A$18:$B$32,2,FALSE)+VLOOKUP(AT14,$A$18:$B$32,2,FALSE)+VLOOKUP(AT15,$A$18:$B$32,2,FALSE))/3
```

I have researched the problem and looks like `AVERAGEIF` looks interesting, however it takes a range of cells as an argument and I want to have three lookup results there.

Comment: For future reference these type of questions (`Excel-Formula`) are better suited to Super User

Answer (score 0):

As long as `AT13`, `AT14` and `AT15` are found once each at most in the lookup range you could use `SUMIF` function divided by COUNTIF

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF($A$18:$A$32,AT13:AT15,$B$18:$B$32))/MAX(1,SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF($A$18:$A$32,AT13:AT15)))`

If there are no values found then MAX function ensures the denominator is 1 to avoid #DIV/0! error and give zero as the result in that case

Comment: This returns 0. Where did lookups go? Athe A18 to A30 range is range that has a lot of values and some empty spaces. I need only 3 values from that range

Comment: I'm suggesting SUMIF because that can do the same as a VLOOKUP where the result is a number.....but allows more flexibility for averaging etc. I changed the formula though (SUM to SUMPRODUCT) - do you get a non-zero value now?

Comment: Now it returns a non zero value that is equal to 0 + value + 0 / 3, instead of value / 1

Comment: So in that instance only 1 of AT13, AT14 and AT15 is present in A18:A32? I can't replicate the problem. In that scenario I just get value/1 = value. ......or do you have all of AT13, 14 and 15 present but with zeroes or blanks in column B?

Comment: The problem is that under AT13,AT14, AT15 lookup result there might be an empty cell